# Dynamic text box working on local pc but not working live

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jquery to add text boxes in the modal and then store the values ajax to my database, But i am surprised to see that the same code works fine on local pc while the same does not work live. Here is my code

Modal (Form)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="form-head_sub">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="">Head Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" name="head" class="form-control" id="Head-name" placeholder="Enter Head Name" required="">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="">Sub Head</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" name="subhead[]" class="sub" id="sub-head" placeholder="Enter Sub Head Name" required="">
                </div>
                <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for=""> </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9" id="target">
                </div>
              </div>
                 <div id="container"></div>
              <input type="button" id="add" value='add'/>

              <div class="form-group"> 
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="save">save
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </form>
```

jquery

```
$(document).on('submit','#form-head_sub', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var head = $('#Head-name').val();
var allValue = new Array();
$('.sub').each(function(){
allValue.push( $(this).val() ); 
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'data/add_headsub.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        head:head,
        subhead:allValue,
        },
.....
```

AJAX page

```
foreach ($_POST['subhead'] as $key=>$value) 
{
    $subh = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $cwditem->add_subhead($subh,$head_id,$user_id);
}
```

All the values the values are inserted in database other then the dynamic text box values

Comment: why does subhead input has square brackets on the name attribute? I don't know about this syntax, but if it is a javascript update, maybe you don't have the same version on your live server

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: '#Head-name' is your dynamic textbox?

Comment: No i am not getting any error, Subhead is my dynamic text box, Null values are added in subhead field

Comment: @FranckNgako the square brackets are used for array

Comment: well it's been a long time since i haven't use php, but i remember that not calling `isset` function used to create trouble. Plus try making a dump of your s_POST['subhead'] in your live environment. At least if you have something in it, it would mean the problem is coming from the database or smth

Comment: Instead of `$key=>$value` try `$value`